# DateTime in sql only comparing the time

Tags: sql-server

```
ID                  DateTime                 Code
----------          --------------           ----------
58                  2015-01-01 20:00:00      1111
58                  2015-01-11 10:00:00      8523
58                  2015-01-11 03:00:00      4555
58                  2015-01-19 00:01:00      8888
 9                  2015-01-01 20:00:00      4444
```

how do i count the number of codes for a specific ID ignoring which date it is but it must be between 20:00:00 and 06:00:00

```
select count(code) as count from table 1 where ID='58' and DateTime between '20:00:00' and '06:00:00'
```

the expected output would be

### count

3

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: If you are using the `Sql server` you can cast your date field as `Time` to get the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(code) as count 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
  ID='58' and 
  (CAST(DateTime as time) >= '20:00' 
   or CAST(DateTime as time) <= '06:00')
```

EDIT: John, I understand the issue. Here is a full solution to handle those cases:

In order to use variables:

```
DECLARE @HourBegin time = '07:00'
DECLARE @HourEnd   time = '17:30'

    SELECT count(code) as count 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE 
      ID='58' and 
      (CAST(DateTime as time) between @HourBegin and @HourEnd or
       ((CAST(DateTime as time) <= @HourEnd or 
        CAST(DateTime as time) >= @HourBegin) and 
           @HourBegin > @HourEnd)
       )
```

Comment: the problem that i realised with this that for instance if i want to change the time to the following cast(datetime as time)>='07:00:00' or cast (datetime as time )<='17:30:00'  it doesnt pick up only for between that time it picks up the code after 17:30:00 as well

Comment: @john I posted an improved answer

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as previous answer, but with hours it looks nicer for me and might be you need DISTINCT code

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT  code) as count 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
  ID='58' and 
  (DATEPART(HOUR,DateTime) >= 20 
   or DATEPART(HOUR,DateTime) < 6)
```

UPDATED: changed from <= 6 to < 6

Comment: no 06:00:01 it isn't included in my answer <= '06:00' exclude that posibility. In your suggestion < 6 will exclude timestamps 06:00:00:000

Comment: yeah, you are too fast :) deleted my comment after I tested it on db but you wrote the answer already

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

This answer applies to `MySQL`.
When I started writing the answer, the question was tagged `mysql` and `sql-server`. The OP edited it in the meantime.

---

This query should do what you want on `MySQL`.

```
SELECT count(code) AS `count` 
FROM `table 1`
WHERE ID='58' 
  AND TIME(`DateTime`) NOT BETWEEN '06:00:01' AND '19:59:59'
```

The `MySQL` function [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) extracts only the time component from a `DATETIME` value.

On version 5.7, MySQL added [support for fractional seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html) (up to 6 digits) on `DATETIME` columns. The query above will include the entries having time greater than `06:00:00` but smaller than `06:00:01` (events that happened during the first second after 6 AM sharp).

For MySQL 5.7 and newer, the correct query is:

```
SELECT count(code) AS `count` 
FROM `table 1`
WHERE ID='58' 
  AND (TIME(`DateTime`) <= '06:00:00' OR '20:00:00' <= TIME(`DateTime`))
```

I don't know about `SQL Server`.